# Where, other than Voltaire, are there other references to "cat's eyes" in 18th century Europe?

Tags: france, 18th-century, literature, medicine

Reading Voltaire’s *[A Philosophical Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_philosophique)*, in the article on character, I found this:

> “If I have a wry nose and cat's eyes I can hide them behind a mask, and can I do more with the character that nature has given me?”

The French is the same:

> <Si j'ai un nez de travers et deux yeux de chat je peut les cacher avec une masque. Puis-je davantage sur le caractère que m'a donné la nature?>

This struck me as an unusual phrase, and I raked through my dictionaries, expecting to find some particular locution, and found nothing, which seemed very odd—I didn’t think it was a phrase one would invent.

Looking further, I discovered that there is a disease called [Cat Eye Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_eye_syndrome) so named because the pupil is deformed in a manner reminiscent of a cat. I imagine Voltaire *might* have met a sufferer, or heard of one (I imagine they could have wound as exhibits in travelling fairs, unless they were lucky).
It’s a rare disease, and I have no idea whether it is more common in Europe than anywhere else.

Is anyone so well read in Voltaire that they could point out other references to ‘les yeux de chat’? Or other uses of the phrase in 18th century Europe?

Comment: I think https://french.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit.

Comment: First thing that leaps to mind is AC/DC's "Back in Black", but that's a bit out of your time window.

Comment: It was almost a coin toss *where* I decided to post this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Cat's eyes" here is translated literally from the French. So we need to figure out what "cat's eyes" meant in 18th century French. The dictionary of *L'Académie Française* from 1740 says

> On dit de celui qui a les yeux entre gris & roux, *qu'il a des yeux de chat*.
>
> One says of someone who has eyes between gray and orange, *that he has cat's eyes.*

This is an unusual color of eyes (I expect they would be called *hazel* in English), and depending on the prevailing standard of beauty for eye color, one might easily want to hide them.

Comment: That is extremely interesting (and leaves me wanting more dictionaries!). Whether it would be seen as a feature or a flaw I imagine depended on how important the person was. I'll wait a day--just in case someone posts something astonishing about Voltaire's knowledge of the medical condition, but I imagine this is the answer.